# checkbox in gridview not checked is true when submit click

Tags: c#, asp.net

checkbox in gridview not checked is flase when submit click But when i modify and update button click checked is TRUE

```
public void addchapselect()
{
    TextBox1.Text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < gvChapter.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)gvChapter.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
        if (chkbox != null)
        {
            if (chkbox.Checked)
            {

                TextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(gvChapter.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text) + ",";

                // ItemValueId = ItemValueId + ",";
                string Name = Convert.ToString(gvChapter.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);



            }
        }
        chkbox.Checked = false;
    }
    if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: on which event this code runs\

Comment: on button click event

Comment: @Atul would you please paste your button click event code ?

Comment: this is function call on submit and modify buuton

Comment: paste your HTML Code and Page Load Code.

Comment: @Atul , why you add ` chkbox.Checked = false;` at the end of looping !

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be you are binding the `Gridview` on `page_load` function.

Bind it inside `!IsPostback` and it should work.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //bind your grid here.
 }
```